# React input type checkbox error with css styling

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox

I've got a table, which creates itself with .map(). Each object in state array gets displayed in the table row with checkbox, which changes state value, and three buttons. I've had too much trouble with checkbox styling, but I've got it, however, now only the first checkbox works. Other checkboxes below can be clicked, but only the first one gets colored. Also, only in the first checkbox the onChange function works, not on others. So, I need that the function and color change would work on all checkboxes, not just the first one.

List code

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        const products = this.props.products;
        return (
            <div className="productList">
                <table className="productTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th className="text-left">Name</th>
                        <th className="text-right">EAN Code</th>
                        <th className="text-right">Type</th>
                        <th className="text-right">Weight</th>
                        <th className="text-right">Color</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Active</th>
                    </tr>
                    {products.map((product, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td className="text-left">{product.name}</td>
                                <td className="text-right">{product.ean}</td>
                                <td className="text-right">{product.type}</td>
                                <td className="text-right">{product.weight}</td>
                                <td className="text-right">{product.color}</td>
                                <td className="text-center">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked={product.active} onChange={(e) => this.props.setProductActive(product, e.target.checked)} />
                                <label for="check" /></td>
                                <td className="text-center"><Link to={{ pathname: "/view", state: { prodIndex: index }}} ><button>View</button></Link></td>
                                <td className="text-center"><Link to={{ pathname: "/edit", state: { prodIndex: index }}} ><button>Edit</button></Link></td>
                                <td className="text-center"><button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(index)}>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Styling

```
}
input[type=checkbox] + label{
    display: block;
    margin: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    content:"";
    border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    border-radius: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:active:before{
    transform:scale(0);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

App Code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProductList from "../ProductList/ProductList";
import NewProd from "../NewProd/NewProd";
import ViewProd from "../ViewProd/ViewProd";
import EditProd from "../EditProd/EditProd";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };
};
/*componentDidMount() {
  let localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
  console.log(localData);
  this.setState({products: localData})
}
setToLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
}*/
handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
  if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return alert("Please fill all empty text spaces");
  } 
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];
  products.push({
      name: this.state.name,
      ean: this.state.ean,
      type: this.state.type,
      weight: this.state.weight,
      color: this.state.color,
      active: false,
  });
  this.setState({ redirect: true, products, 
    name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", active: false},
    () => {this.setState({redirect: false})}
  );
}
handleEditFormSubmit = (index, e) => {
  if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return alert("Please fill all empty text spaces");
  } 
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];
  products.splice(index, 1, {name: this.state.name,
    ean: this.state.ean,
    type: this.state.type,
    weight: this.state.weight,
    color: this.state.color,
    active: false})
  this.setState({ redirect: true, products, name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", active: false}, 
  () => this.setState({redirect: false})
  );
  }
canBeSubmitted() {
  const {name, ean, type, weight, color} = this.state;
  return (name.length > 0 && 
    ean.length > 0 && 
    type.length > 0 && 
    weight.length > 0 && 
    color.length > 0
  )
}
handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({...this.state,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  };

deleteProduct = (delIndex) => {
  let products = [...this.state.products].filter((product, index) => index !== delIndex);
  this.setState({ products }/*,
    () => this.setToLocalStorage());*/
};
isActive = () => {
  this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
}
setProductActive = (product, active) => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    products: state.products.map(p => p.name === product.name ? { ...p, active } : p)
  }));
}

render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <ProductList products={this.state.products} 
      deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct}
      setProductActive={this.setProductActive} />
      <Link to={{ pathname: "/create"}} ><button>Create</button></Link>
      <Route path="/create" render={(props) => <NewProd {...props} 
      products = {this.state.products}
      redirect = {this.state.redirect}
      handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
      handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
      newName={this.state.name}
      newEan={this.state.ean}
      newType={this.state.type}
      newWeight={this.state.weight}
      newColor={this.state.color} />} />
      <Route path="/view" render={(props) => <ViewProd {...props} products={this.state.products} />} />
      <Route path="/edit" render={(props) => <EditProd {...props} products={this.state.products} 
      handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
      handleEditFormSubmit={this.handleEditFormSubmit}
      editName={this.state.name}
      editEan={this.state.ean}
      editType={this.state.type}
      editWeight={this.state.weight}
      editColor={this.state.color}
  redirect={this.state.redirect} />} /> 
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please update your snippets to include all the relevant code? A minimal, working example is super helpful and allows us to help more efficiently. As an alternative, a JSFiddle or similar is really helpful.

Comment: Hello. As for some reason I'm unable to update codesandbox with new code, I've put in the main app code as well. However, I don't think it will be necessary, because everything was working fine, until I applied styles to the active checkbox. This is probably a css syntax issue or clash with onChange function, something like that. Again, the highest/first checkbox in the list is working perefectly fine, but it is also the only one to respond when you press on other checkboxes.

Comment: Can it be that once the function maps over all objects on array and gives them each a checkbox with the same id="check", that this may be the problem? Multiple checkboxes with the same id and only one works?

Comment: Yup, that was the case, problem solved.